# Which Linux distributions offer a stable release based on the 3.10 kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, distributions

I'm looking for a stable Linux distribution (preferably a well-known one) based on the 3.10 kernel. So far I have identified Gentoo as one such distribution. But I'm having trouble finding any others.

What other distributions currently offer a *stable* release based on the 3.10 series kernel?

Comment: Slackware 14.1 uses kernel 3.10.17 by default

Comment: Debian stable has that kernel version in stable backports.

Comment: almost every linux distro call themselves stable, take a look at [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/)

Comment: @brm: Thanks. Any reason you decided against submitting that as an answer? ;)

Comment: I found that one sentence a bit short for an actual answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try Archlinux with [Linux LTS 3.10.XX-X](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/linux-lts/) which is based on the Linux 3.10 LTS release from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/).

Archlinux by default comes with the latest stable kernel wich currently is 3.12.9-2 but is quiet simple to install the LTS version because it's in the official Archlinux repositories.

To install it and generate the grub entry run:

```
$ pacman -S linux-lts
$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```